# There seems to be a postmaster servicing the old cluster. | Upgrade from postgres 9.3

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I am working on upgrading postgres from version 9.3 to 10. I have encountered a lot of issues along the way since the install is way more custom done than it should be (People here LOVE complex and custom/security through obscurity).

Far as I can tell it has something to do with `pg_pool` but am not too sure on that one.

**Upgrade command:**

```
time ${PGBINNEW}/pg_upgrade --old-bindir=${PGBINOLD} --new-bindir=${PGBINNEW} --old-datadir=${PGDATAOLD} --new-datadir=${PGDATANEW} --old-port=${PGPORT} --new-port=${PGPORTNEW} --jobs=$(nproc | awk '{ {print ($1 > 4) ? 4 : ($1 == 1 ? 1 : $1 - 1)} }') --link --username=postgres
```

**Error:**

```
There seems to be a postmaster servicing the old cluster.
Please shutdown that postmaster and try again.
Failure, exiting
```